# Bounty grace period shouldn't be there if no answers are posted

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I recently put some bounties on a [few](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47762/what-is-the-unit-of-measurement-for-the-velocity-display) [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28998/how-can-i-get-the-potion-in-thirsty-level-46-of-spelling-jungle) where I was interested in finding out the answer.  However, none have been posted during that time.  Even without answers, I have to wait out the grace period to 'award' the bounty, which I can't do.  This locks down the total number of active bounties I can offer so I can't put new ones out on other questions.

Is it possible to remove the grace period for bounties if no answers have been posted?

Comment: @Andrew Sure, but since there are no answers as of the closing of the question and I can't award the bounty to any answers that appear after the start of the grace period, shouldn't the bounty be effectively over at that point?  Whats the point of waiting another 24 hours, the end result is still the same.

Comment: Good point, actually. I was thinking in the wrong direction.

Comment: I would have posted this a while ago but I didn't have a good rationale.  I missed the fact that it prevents you from offering another bounty, for no good reason.  +1

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it an answer that is posted during the grace period can still be eligible for the bounty: [Are answers posted during the grace period eligible for bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134943/are-answers-posted-during-the-grace-period-eligible-for-bounties). So this allows people who see the bounty in the last few minutes to post an answer 10 or 20 minutes later (after the bounty has ended) and still receive the bounty. If an answerless bounty ended without a grace period then this would be impossible

Comment: well, during the grace period the bounty isn't listed in the featured list anymore so the chances of it getting an answer is quite low.

Comment: Agreed but the last few minutes of a bounty gets the most views so someone posting an answer just after the bounty ends are reasonably high

Comment: maybe for the main site like stackoverflow, but for other sites that's not the case