# Message regarding a bounty after it expired without an answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties

I started a bounty at 11:52 on Nov. 7th and it expired yesterday after seven days. No answer has been posted and I know I will end up losing this reputation.

Now, it is 12:12 on Nov. 15th, eight days and 20 minutes passed since I started it. But I still see the message below:

[image]

I understand the purpose of this message.

How long is as soon as possible? Is this message or extension useful when there is no answer?

Note: The reason I asked this question was this grace period is blocking me from starting another bounty. When there is no answer, I don't see any usefulness of this grace period or message.

Comment: This is known as bounty grace period, which lasts for one day, give or take an hour, after a bounty ends.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The reason I asked this question was this grace period is blocking me from starting another bounty. When there is no answer, I don't see any usefulness of this grace period or message.

Comment: It's not mentioned in your question at all. Anyway, there's already existing feature request exactly for this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120858/bounty-grace-period-shouldnt-be-there-if-no-answers-are-posted (you can start a bounty on it, then when it will reach its grace period without answers it would be funny ;))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Can you close this as dupe? I will accept it.

Comment: Too late, already used my hammer. Plus, in the current form of your question it would be wrong and misleading.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh, I didn't know you have the hammer. Thanks.

Comment: Three hammers,  only [tag:bug] hammer is missing. :)